# How and where to implement AdMob App Id in unity project?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am a learner and i am working in unity and testing all the features. Now i want to add ads in my project using adMob but the problem is AdMob has provided me an App Id and i don't know how and where to Implement it... I know what's Ad Unit Id but this App ID i am not getting it... I have gone through so many tutorials on you tube but in some video tutorials(a year older) they are not getting any APP ID and in some video(newer ones) they are not at all talking about APP ID and just working with only Ad Unit Id.

I am getting some id's like this

> 1. Complete the instructions in the Google Mobile Ads SDK guide using this app ID:
>      spinaroundca-app-pub-8xxxxx63xxxxxxx8~99xxxxxxxx
> 2. Follow the banner implementation guide to integrate the SDK. You'll specify ad type, size, and placement when you integrate the code using this ad unit ID:
>      bannnerca-app-pub-8xxxxxxx7xxxxxx8/32xxxxxxxx
> 3. Review the AdMob policies to ensure your implementation complies.

Comment: Please edit your question to use proper grammar. Sentences start with a capital and end with punctuation. Also focus your question on a specific problem. It is unclear to me what specific problem you have, which means that the question is too broad or does not contain the necessary information to determine what you are actually asking.

Comment: All i want to know is how to implement App id to my unity android app.

Answer (score 0):

In the menu goto Assets=>Google Mobile Ads->Settings
There's a textbox in the inspector where you paste the AppId

Comment: Is it possible to do this at runtime? For example if I want to change the App ID after I load all Firebase RemoteConfig data, how do I do it?